# Why is a column value always the value of that column in first row?

Tags: reporting-services, group-by

In one of my reports, I have a dataset with following fields:

```
CategoryID  ProductID  PackType  NumberOfItems
1              1          1          2
1              1          2          4
1              1          3          12
1              2          1          4
1              2          2          8
1              2          3          12
2              1          1          3
2              1          2          6
...
```

The output that I need is:

GroupHeaderA:

- `CategoryID`
- `SUM(NumberOfItems where PackType = 1)`
- `SUM(NumberOfItems where PackType = 3)`
- `SUM((NumberOfItems where PackType = 2) - (NumberOfItems where PackType = 1))`
- `SUM((NumberOfItems where PackType = 3) - (NumberOfItems where PackType = 2))`

GroupDetailA:

- `ProductID`
- `NumberOfItems where PackType = 1`
- `NumberOfItems where PackType = 3`
- `(NumberOfItems where PackType = 2) -(NumberOfItems where PackType = 1)`
- `(NumberOfItems where PackType = 3) -(NumberOfItems where PackType = 2)`

To achieve this I have created a ParentGroup on CategoryId and a child group on ProductId. In details section of ProductID, I have placed the NumberOfItems and PackType. On child group header I place:

expression_1 to get the value of NumberOfItems  where packtype is 1

```
=IIF(Fields!PackType.Value =  1, NumberOfItems, 0)
```

expression_2 to get the value of NumberOfItems where packtype is max

```
=IIF(Fields!PackType.Value =  Max(Fields!PackType.Value),NumberOfItems ,0)
```

But the expression is not returning correct. I found that the `Fields!PackType.Value` always comes as 1. Why does a column in footer of detail group always display the value of its first row?

Please tell me if there's another approach I can follow to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are accessing a field in the details group, then references to any fields that aren't a grouping criteria need to be in an aggregate.

Instead of `=IIF(Fields!PackType.Value =  1, NumberOfItems, 0)` try:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!PackType.Value =  1, NumberOfItems, 0))
```

Instead of `=IIF(Fields!PackType.Value =  Max(Fields!PackType.Value),NumberOfItems ,0)`

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!PackType.Value =  Max(Fields!PackType.Value , "YourGroupNameHere"),NumberOfItems ,0))
```

This second one, an aggregate containing an aggregate won't work in SSRS prior to 2008R2. I haven't used this sort of expression much, so I'm not even sure if it will work in R2. IF this doesn't work then I woudl to write some embedded code to get this.